# how to understand callback source?

Tags: javascript, debugging, callback

I have js function renderTerminalsOnMap .
This function invokes as callback.

code looks like this:

```
 $.getJSON('getTerminalinsideRectangle.json', {
                northEastLat : map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
                northEastLng : map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(),
                southWestLat : map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(),
                southWestLng : map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
            }, renderTerminalsOnMap)
```

In debug I want to understand which event was a cause of renderTerminalsOnMap invocation.
In callStack I don't see this information.

I use Google Chrome for debug.

Please help me to found out.

Answer (score 0):

So you need call stack for $.getJSON call, right? If so and if you can modify source code, you can store stack trace and show it when actual render called, like:

```
var obj = {stack: {}};
Error.captureStackTrace && Error.captureStackTrace(obj, getStackTrace);

$.getJSON(....,
    function() {
        window.console.info(obj);
        renderTerminalsOnMap(arguments);
    });
```

should work in Chrome, don't know about other browsers.

Comment: I have different functions also, which use this function as callback.

Comment: yes, so you need to add same code in all places, if you need to know which function registered this callback

Comment: I don't have this info unfortunately

Comment: you can just search in source code for function name )

Comment: Is there other ways? I don't like this

Comment: when you callback called, event creates new context, and context of handler attachment is lost, so only some hacks are possible. For example, if you always use it in getJSON - override this function with some proxy and do this job in proxy. Do you have some single point?

Comment: Ok. I understood you. I just wanted to investigate debug possibility for javascript

Comment: May be some deep possibilities like prototype override exist, but i'm not aware about such solutions. I debugged a lot of events in my library, and provided exactly this mechanism in auto-generated event bus and ajax proxy, because it's always useful to know where handler was attached, especially if it wasn't triggered